What have I done wrong in this double integral?
The exercise I was solving asks to calculate $$\iint_{D} ydxdy$$ where $D$ is limited by $x=0, x^2+y^2=1, y^2=2x, y\ge0$.
What I have done is to use the graphs of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y^2=2x$ in order to write $D$ as $$D:= \{x,y: \frac{y^2}{2} \lt x \lt \sqrt{1-y^2}, 0 \lt y \lt \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}\}$$ So the integral looks like $$\int_0^{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}} \int_{y^2/2}^\sqrt{1-y^2} y dxdy$$ Calculating the integral in respect on $x$ $$\int_0^{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}} (y\sqrt{1-y^2}-y^3/2)dx$$ and calculating this integral I obtain that $$\iint_{D} ydxdy=-\frac{1}{3}(3-2\sqrt{2})^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)^2+\frac{1}{3}$$ However, the solution of the exercise is supposed to be $\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{32}-5)$.

You don't have the correct region. You have to choose the one that contains the line $x=0$, not $y=0$.

@NinadMunshi thank you very much

In a picture, courtesy of Desmos

the problem was you integrated over the green region, when the question specified the red region.
